# Juniper SRX, workstation on SRX switch port cannot ping reth interface

Tags: firewall, juniper, srx

- I have a SRX345 firewall that has a workstation hanging off one of its ethernet ports.
- The workstation cannot ping the SRX reth interface, reth1.50 (its default gw) even though the   ethernet port is configured as access and in vlan 50.
- The workstation and reth1.50 are in the same subnet and security zone.
- There is also in intrazone security policy
- Reth1.50 has host-inbound system service ping.
- What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add the (sanitized) configuration to your question, as text using the editor's `{}` option. We cannot just guess what you did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A reth interface on the SRX is a Layer 3 interface - that is to say that VLAN tags are only added to traffic from a reth interface as it egresses the physical port(s) you have bound it to - it does not interact with VLANs configured on the SRX in any way.

If you are just trying to provide a gateway to your workstation, create an `irb` interface, bind it to your VLAN and add it to the required security-zone eg:

```
set interfaces irb unit 50 family inet address 192.168.50.1/24
set vlans v50 vlan-id 50
set vlans v50 l3-interface irb.50
set security zones security-zone WORKSTATIONS interfaces irb.50
```

(though I would advise using a VLAN tag other than 50 since it is being used elsewhere on your network).

Alternatively, connect the workstation to a switch downstream from the SRX that the reth is connected to in VLAN 50 and it will be able to route via the reth1.50 interface.